# Install an exe to a particular folder using bash script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to install an exe using a batch script. This is the command that works perfectly to install the exe:

```
C:\downloads\python-3.6.5-amd64.exe /silent /norestart
```

What I really want is that the python36 folder that is created after the installation, should be created in a particular directory for example in

```
"C:\Program Files"
```

I have tried

```
set pythonInstallDir= "C:\Program Files"
C:\Users\eyds\Downloads\python-3.6.5-amd64.exe /silent /norestart TargetDir=%pythonInstallDir%
```

It doesn't work. The folder is still stored in the default location. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It is important you specify a python folder as path and not just `C:\Program Files` as it will then dump the executables inside the root of it..

```
set "pythonInstallDir=C:\Program Files\Python3.6.5"
C:\Users\eyds\Downloads\python-3.6.5-amd64.exe /silent /norestart TargetDir="%pythonInstallDir%"
```

Note the double quotes are very important here to cater for whitespace, also I removed the space after `=` in `set`

Here I tested it to program files and you'll see it works.

[image]